# C++ Variable Redifinition in Scope

Tags: c++, gcc

It's been a while since I wrote C++. How is it possible that the code below compiles in C++14 without even a warning?

```
int x = 0;
if (true) {
    int x = 2;
}
```

Compiler:

```
gcc (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Flags:

```
CXX_FLAGS =  -std=c++14 -Wall -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno- 
builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free -O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -I ${INCLUDES}
```

Comment: why should there be a warning?

Comment: You are allowed to shadow objects from outer scopes with new ones in the local scope in c++. See [name hiding](http://en.cppreference.com/book/scope#Name_hiding).

Comment: VS 2017 yields `warning C4456: declaration of 'x' hides previous local declaration`

Comment: No warning because it is and always has been perfectly valid C++. However, if you fear a programming error on your part, there's `-Wshadow`.

Comment: Warnings are what certain compiler vendors decide what they want to warn you of.  There is no mandate on what code should give a warning.

Comment: `-Wshadow` has been supported for a while: [gcc 4.4 example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yDWUE3kDXuZMvEJS) and [clang 3.1 example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qr9Q5YumNMCZztdX). It's a good warning to have on in my humble opinion.

Comment: Idk what's up with the downvotes, this is a legit question with an MCVE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a variable within a tighter scope with the same name as one in the outer scope has *always* been a feature of C++. Occasionally it can be useful.

Some compilers will warn you, but if they follow the C++ standard, they should not issue an error.

Languages like Java disallow it but that can be annoying, particularly when moving  blocks of code around.

Comment: Your mention of Java just made me recall a truly unpleasant bit of refactoring back in Uni...

Comment: Porting C++ to Java is a bit like trying to plug a horse and cart into a Tesla charging point.

Comment: nice point to put on my why-i-dislike-java list, though i also cannot find a good example where hiding would be useful.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd say it's more like installing the horse on a merry-go-round

Comment: I think we can all agree it's a cruel thing to do, no matter the exact fate of the horse